# How do you find out whether your disc is SATA or not?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata, device-manager

I have a laptop and am trying to figure out if my disc drive is a SATA or not *without opening it*.

Is there a way to find out? I looked at Computer Management, but I can't tell if my drive is SATA or not:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is SATA. The `ST910021AS` corresponds to the model of the drive, which can be found [here](http://shopper.cnet.com/internal-hard-drives/seagate-momentus-7200-1/4014-9998_9-31421187.html).

Comment: @thanks thepurplepixel: I wasn't even aware that it was a model number...

Answer (score 3):

Look up the model number? http://www.seagate.com/support/disc/manuals/sata/100320528a.pdf